# Why is Kurapika so powerful?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I know he made ​​a contract with his own soul or something like that.  But if this Nen is so powerful, how come he is the only who used it in the series?

I also watched the previous version(1999), and there was no one who did this type of contract besides him.

Comment: I strongly believe that impose a limitation, is a unnatural way to become strong and have fatal consequences, both of the Nen users that imposed theirselves had very bad consequences to their health, so a good nen master, never imposed such limitation in order to increase power. Gon and Kurapica suffered with this practice, in fact after Kurapica knew about Gon health state after Chimera ant, he regrets tell him how to increase Nen with such limitation conditions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kurapika's scarlet eyes allow him to shift from becoming a Conjurer to a Specialist because of their unique nature. This ability, Emperor Time, allows him to utilize all the types of Nen to 100% efficiency.

Kurapika has a Nen blade chain wrapped around his heart. Kurapika imposed a limitation onto this chain, it can only be used to deal with members of the Phantom Troupe. If this condition is violated, Kurapika will die. This condition (a [Limitation](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nen#Vows_.26_Limitations), a Vow with a punishment) was needed in order to increase the strength of the ability.

Comment: But this does not tell why is he the only one that uses Vow with a punishment, that is so strong.

Comment: There are other vow users, but what makes Purapika powerful is that he can use ALL Nen types at 100% to supplement his other abilities like the Nen Chain. Other Wise he would have been at a disadvantage against Uvogin.

Comment: Who did also use vow Nen in the series?

Comment: Kite's Crazy Slots increases the power of his individual weapons by making a Vow/Contract prohibiting him from being able to select which weapon to use.

Comment: I meant in the anime, sorry for not mentioned.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju I can't say for sure, because the whole Nen Contract thing was jut introduced in the York New arc.

Comment: Note that the "limitation and vow" only apply to one use of the chain, as an unbreakable binding.  He is free to use it in other ways, but it would kill him if he bound anyone not in the Phantom Troupe.  We see, for example, him use the chain as a truth-diviner against other guard-applicants.

Answer (score 5):

Kurapika uses vows and limitations. [The stronger the vows and limitations are, the stronger the Nen.](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nen)

> a student of Nen can increase the overall power of an individual skill by stating a self-imposed restriction that forces even more conditions on it.

Kurapika is the one of the only characters shown who uses such strong vows and limitations because of its risk. If he makes one wrong move and attacks somebody who isn't a spider, he will die. For most people, this is a risk that isn't worth taking because they could easily make a mistake - death does not leave any second chanced. Kurapika took on this risk because he was desperate for a way to beat the spiders.

On top of this, only being able to use your Nen on a specific group of people, especially one that is only thirteen members, limits the use of your powers substantially. Kurapika's power was one developed exclusively for fighting the spiders but most other Nen users would want to be able to use their power more generally.

However, other characters do use weaker versions of vows and limitations. For example, Bomber must tell all his victims about his powers before using it, which means he loses the advantage of anonymity.

Combined with his specialist power of Emperor Time, which means he can use all types of Nen with 100% efficiency, Kurapika's Nen becomes very powerful. Emperor Time is very useful because one of the major weaknesses of Nen can be attributed to not being the right 'type'. Killua is bad at emitting aura ([Chimera Ant arc - Chapter 237 - Page 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjeY2.png)) and this is presumably because he is a transmuter. The same with [Machi](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Machi).

> If the threads leave Machi's fingers, their ultimate strength drops significantly.

Enhancers have the advantage of being able to enhance their power. A transmuter only has 40% of this efficiency and so on so forth.

Forcibly learning a Nen of a type that doesn't suit you can result in one losing the ability to perform other Nen skills. Hisoka calls this running out of memory.

With a combination of these two factors, Kurapika's Nen is far more powerful than most Nen users.

Answer (score 1):

It's his Emperor Time, It boosts his Nen Capacity to significant Power Levels. If you put things in perspective, only the Chain Jail is imposed on the spiders and not on everything else. Kurapika himself is above any human coz he's Kuruta and with his eyes he can do everything in a berserk like state.

In numbers, Normal Kurapakia Physical Power 100 now add 350 because of emperor time that makes it 450. His got a lets say 250 nen Capacity.

Now for Uvon to attack him with a 1000phys+1500nen = 2200 attack power over all, Kurapika has to have the same amount or near that to negate the attack. So Emperor time boosts his Nen output as well, from 250 to 2000. so lets add Kurapikas 450phys+2000nen = 2450 defense power.

Uvon = 2500 attack power, 
Kurapika(EmperorTime) = 2450 Defense, 
Kurapika Normal = 350 defense

To simplify and tie in all the other answers.
Kurapica's chain jail is the only chain that has a condition and therefore nen boost.
Kurapica himself as a kuruta gets a boost in physical abilities when his scarlet eyes turns on.
So therefore for Kurapica to negate Uvon's Big Bang impact, he could have had a high boost in Nen as well to augment his over all defense.

This is reasonable because Kurapica(for arguments sake) is only a let's say 20 in his regular form while Uvon is a high 100. For a 20 to tank a 100 it should be rational to think that he has a boost in attack and defense because of one hax ability. And from what we've seen, no chain gives him that advantage, it could only have been his scarlet eyes and therefore Emperor Time.

This chapter explains it very well, the nature of nen. It's page 19, read the whole issue to get a good grip of it's logic. "when you're eyes turn red your aura considerably increased"
http://mangafox.me/manga/hunter_x_hunter/v09/c083/19.html

Comment: How did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: It's simplified. It's basically saying Kurapica blocked Uvon's 100% Bigbang Impact due to hax ability. In all sense he is nowhere near Uvon's power so it's the only explanation. How else could he have blocked that BBI when he is physically weaker than Uvon, so it's gotta be in the Nen factor enhancing his defense. For that you need equal output to negate the attacking force

Answer (score 0):

Kurapika is powerful because he is a part of the Kurta Clan. Whenever his eyes turn red it boosts his physical and nen capabilities, and changes his nature into a specialist instead of a conjurer. His specialist ability(Emperor Time) enables 100% usage of all nen categories without limits. Making him a jack of all trades whom can master anything based on his characteristics.

On the condition part, every nen ability can be enhanced with a condition, how much stricter the condition the more powerful the ability. His chain jail is only applicable to the Spiders, which isn't something you'd want to survive in the HxH world. Good thing for him he's a kuruta with an extremely hax ability.

Answer (score 0):

In a recently released chapter ([Chapter 364](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_364)), it's stated that Emperor Time has an additional price: for every second while this ability is activated, Kurapika loses one hour of his lifespan. So, besides the Vows and Limitations of (some of) the chains, Emperor Time was under a powerful vow which boosted its power.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gon turning into his adult form to defeat the Chimera Ant, Pitu. He vowed never to user NEN again just to gain that boost of Nen. Just like what the others have mentioned, Kurapika only has CHAIN JAIL wrapped into this vow in order to make it stronger in addition to his emperor time. He can still use the other 4 chains against other enemies but they will never be at the same strength as the CHAIN JAIL against the spider.